# Migrating Nested Data from the Realtime Database to Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I´m migrating a Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore and I have nested data

and I have nested data from which I want to create a collection.

Example:

```
"data" : {
  "-LYBzlXPoN0137KRLovk" : {
    "-LYC-HHqDFgL9PovJiBr" : {
      "age" : 35,
      "country" : "Country",
      "date" : "2019-02-08T13:07:10+01:00",
      "gender" : "male",
      "id" : 1549627467620,
    },
    "age" : 35,
    "country" : "Country",
    "date" : "2019-02-08T13:04:27+01:00",
    "gender" : "male",
    "id" : 1549627467620,
```

I want to create a subcollection from the nested array in Firestore. Therefore I tried the following (Cloud Function):

```
exports.migrateVisits = functions.database.ref('/data/{key}/{nestedKey}')
    .onWrite((change:any, context:any) => {
        // Get a reference to the Firestore document of the changed user
        let userDoc = admin.firestore()
            .collection(`data/{key}/nestedKeys`)
            .doc(context.params.nestedKey);
        // If this user has been deleted, delete in Firestore also
        if (!change.after.exists()) {
            return userDoc.delete();
        }
        // Get the user object with the new changes,
        // as opposed to its value before the edit
        let userData = change.after.val();
        // Now update Firestore with that change

        return userDoc.set(userData);
    });
```

But I get the error: `Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.`

Do you have any idea to migrate in the best way nested subdata?

**Update for Renaud**

```
exports.migrateVisits = functions.database.ref('/data/users/{userId}/visits/{visit}')
    .onWrite((change:any, context:any) => {
        let userData = change.after.val();
        const mainDocObj:any = {};

        let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

        Object.keys(userData).forEach(e => {
            console.log(e);
            if (
                e == 'age' ||
                e == 'country' ||
                e == 'date' ||
                e == 'gender' ||
                e == 'id' ||
                e == 'lastVisit' ||
                e == 'magazineRoute' ||
                e == 'magazineRouteDone' ||
                e == 'magazineRouteLastDate' ||
                e == 'name' ||
                e == 'notice' ||
                e == 'onNextVisit' ||
                e == 'pause' ||
                e == 'placements' ||
                e == 'plz' ||
                e == 'street' ||
                e == 'tag' ||
                e == 'type'
            ) {  //here, add the other main keys, e.g. with ['gender', 'age', 'country', ....].includes(e)
                mainDocObj[e] = userData[e];
            } else {
                //it needs to be added as a doc in the sub-collection
                const subDocRef = admin
                    .firestore()
                    .collection(`users/${context.params.userId}/vi/${context.params.visit}/rv`)
                    .doc(e);
                batch.set(subDocRef, userData[e]);
            }
        });

        //We first write the mainDoc
        console.log(mainDocObj);
        return admin
            .firestore()
            .collection(`users/${context.params.userId}/vi`)
            .doc(context.params.visit)
            .set(mainDocObj)
            .then(() => {
                //We then write the children in one batch
                return batch.commit();
            });
    });
```

Comment: What's the type of your `data` varaible that you are passing to the `collection` function?

Comment: That should be an Array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
exports.migrateVisits = functions.database.ref('/data/{key}/{nestedKey}')
    .onWrite((change:any, context:any) => {
        // Get a reference to the Firestore document of the changed user

        const key = context.params.key;

        const userDoc = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('data/' + key + '/nestedKeys')              
          .doc(context.params.nestedKey);

        // If this user has been deleted, delete in Firestore also
        if (!change.after.exists()) {
            return userDoc.delete();
        }
        // Get the user object with the new changes,
        // as opposed to its value before the edit
        let userData = change.after.val();
        // Now update Firestore with that change

        return userDoc.set(userData);
    });
```

You have to use `context.params` to get values of the `path`.

---

**UPDATE** following our comments.

The main point to note is that since we now listen at the level of the `/data/{key}` you have to distinguish the data that belongs to the main doc from the one that belongs to the children. In the code below I propose to do that based on the data name (gender, date, age, id...). If, while looping, you encounter a data item with another name (e.g. an id like `-LYC-HHqDFgL9PovJiBr`) it means it is a children doc.

Another point to note is the use of a batch write, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Also, I let you take in charge the check if the doc is deleted on not. Another aspect you might have to adapt is the management of children that are already existing, in the case you modify the age under e.g. the node `-LYC-HHqDFgL9PovJiBr`, because, in this case the trigger will still happens at the level of the `/data/{key}`.

```
exports.migrateVisits = functions.database
  .ref('/data/{key}')
  .onWrite((change:any, context:any) => {
    const key = context.params.key;
    let userData = change.after.val();
    const mainDocObj = {};

    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    Object.keys(userData).forEach(e => {
      if (e === 'gender') {  //here, add the other main keys, e.g. with ['gender', 'age', 'country', ....].includes(e)
        mainDocObj[e] = userData[e];
      } else {
        //it needs to be added as a doc in the sub-collection
        const subDocRef = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('data/' + key + '/nestedKeys')
          .doc(e);
        batch.set(subDocRef, userData[e]);
      }
    });

    //We first write the mainDoc
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('data')
      .doc(key)
      .set(mainDocObj)
      .then(() => {
        //We then write the children in one batch
        return batch.commit();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, my fault! :) And how I can save also the data into the key-document? With current code the function creates an empty key value with the sub-collection. How do I can achieve to migrate the whole content?

Comment: Give me some few minutes, in order to have a look

Comment: Sure. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Not 100% sure what exact value you want to write (with `nestedKey`or not?) but the updated code should work. Note that if the /data/{key} document doesn't exists before, it will appear in italic in the Firebase console database viewer: this means that the sub-collection exists but the parent doc does not (a sub-collection can very well exist without parent document, and technically speaking is not linked to this document: they just have a part of their paths in common).

Comment: In my json above you see that my parent key (document) has also values...but these values are not imported to firestore...firestore creates only an empty document instead the values. Do I need two functions to achieve this? First function for parent key values and second function for sub array?

Comment: See the addition to my comment above. The upper parent doc will not be created when you add a doc to the sub-collection. If you need it you need to first create it, then write to the sub-collection

Comment: So yes - I understand you. Do you have an idea how to solve it in one single cloud function to create first the parent document with values and then the subcollection?

Comment: Yes I do :-) give me some few minutes

Comment: One question: the Cloud Function trigger needs to be a the level of the nestedKey /data/{key}/{nestedKey}? Do you confirm?

Comment: It would be perfect if the trigger would be at the level `/data/{key}`

Comment: It does not work.. :/ Log: `Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    at Validator.(anonymous function).err [as isDocument] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:93:27)
    at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:225:25)
    at Object.keys.forEach.e (/user_code/lib/index.js:137:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at exports.migrateVisits.functions.database.ref.onWrite....`

Comment: Update: I don´t know what I did...but it works now! :D